# Unable to install php-mcrypt

Tags: php, yum, mcrypt, centos6

I have followed so many online guides now about install php-mcrypt but none of these seem to be playing ball i am getting a lot of dependency errors.

All help would be greatly appreciated

when doing a yum update after installing an rpm i get the following

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.krystal.co.uk
 * extras: mirrors.ukfast.co.uk
 * rpmforge: apt.sw.be
 * updates: mirror.krystal.co.uk
Setting up Update Process

Resolving Dependencies

--> Running transaction check

---> Package mod_wsgi.x86_64 0:3.2-3.el6 will be updated

---> Package mod_wsgi.x86_64 0:3.4-1.el5.rf will be an update

--> Processing Dependency: libpython2.4.so.1.0()(64bit) for package: mod_wsgi     3.4-1.el5.rf.x86_64
---> Package python-babel.noarch 0:0.9.4-5.1.el6 will be updated
---> Package python-babel.noarch 0:0.9.5-1.el5.rf will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 for package: python-babel-0.9.5-1.el5.rf.noarch
---> Package python-beaker.noarch 0:1.3.1-7.el6 will be updated
---> Package python-beaker.noarch 0:1.5.3-1.el5.rf will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 for package: python-beaker-1.5.3-1.el5.rf.noarch
---> Package python-genshi.x86_64 0:0.5.1-7.1.el6 will be updated
---> Package python-genshi.noarch 0:0.6-2.el5.rf will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 for package: python-genshi-0.6-2.el5.rf.noarch
---> Package python-mako.noarch 0:0.3.4-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package python-mako.noarch 0:0.3.5-1.el5.rf will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 for package: python-mako-0.3.5-1.el5.rf.noarch
---> Package python-markupsafe.x86_64 0:0.9.2-4.el6 will be updated
---> Package python-markupsafe.x86_64 0:0.11-1.el5.rf will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 for package: python-markupsafe-0.11-1.el5.rf.x86_64
---> Package python-netaddr.noarch 0:0.7.5-4.el6 will be updated
---> Package python-netaddr.noarch 0:0.7.10-1.el5.rf will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 for package: python-netaddr-0.7.10-1.el5.rf.noarch
---> Package python-paramiko.noarch 0:1.7.5-2.1.el6 will be updated
---> Package python-paramiko.noarch 0:1.7.6-1.el5.rf will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 for package: python-paramiko-1.7.6-1.el5.rf.noarch
---> Package python-pygments.noarch 0:1.1.1-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package python-pygments.noarch 0:1.4-1.el5.rf will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 for package: python-pygments-1.4-1.el5.rf.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python-genshi-0.6-2.el5.rf.noarch (rpmforge)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
       Installed: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (@updates)
           python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 (base)
           python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: python-markupsafe-0.11-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
       Installed: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (@updates)
           python(abi) = 2.6
       Available: python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 (base)
           python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: python-pygments-1.4-1.el5.rf.noarch (rpmforge)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
       Installed: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (@updates)
           python(abi) = 2.6
       Available: python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 (base)
           python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: python-beaker-1.5.3-1.el5.rf.noarch (rpmforge)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
       Installed: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (@updates)
           python(abi) = 2.6
       Available: python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 (base)
           python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: python-mako-0.3.5-1.el5.rf.noarch (rpmforge)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
       Installed: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (@updates)
           python(abi) = 2.6
       Available: python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 (base)
           python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: python-paramiko-1.7.6-1.el5.rf.noarch (rpmforge)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
       Installed: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (@updates)
           python(abi) = 2.6
       Available: python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 (base)
           python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: python-netaddr-0.7.10-1.el5.rf.noarch (rpmforge)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
       Installed: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (@updates)
           python(abi) = 2.6
       Available: python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 (base)
           python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: python-babel-0.9.5-1.el5.rf.noarch (rpmforge)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
       Installed: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (@updates)
           python(abi) = 2.6
       Available: python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 (base)
           python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: mod_wsgi-3.4-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
       Requires: libpython2.4.so.1.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Hello Alvaro, how do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates yum is trying to install from the repoforge el5 repository instead of el6. This needs to be corrected.

Here is the solution for this problem:-

solution :- reinstall rpmforge

go to terminal

01.

[root@gts250 rajiv]# su

02.

[root@gts250 rajiv]# wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm

03.

[root@gts250 rajiv]# rpm -Uvh rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm

04.

[root@gts250 rajiv]# yum clean all

05.

[root@gts250 rajiv]# yum update